# JSON Analyzer / Inspector to tell false position

Tags: json

I am having trouble with (fairly large) JSON files that seem to have some errors but I cannot find them (PHP programmer).

I search for a tool that will read a JSON file and tell me the position (char number) where it thinks a failure or inconsitency will be.

I have searched for hours now, but only find some websites that are not helpful with such big files (multiple MB)

Any help appreciated!
jwka

Comment: Try http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try these formatters

[Formatter for big files](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html)

[jsonformatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)